# Error with Future.js in Meteor Application

Tags: javascript, meteor

First post here.

I am working through David Turnbull's book titled *Your First Meteor Application*, and the app is starting to break after I run the command

`meteor add accounts-password`

After running this command, I am getting an error message saying an exception is being thrown at line 245 of future.js.  I removed accounts-password using `remove`, but am still getting this message.

```
/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:245
                    throw(ex);
                          ^
Error: EACCES, rename     '/Users/kishanpatel/Meteor/leaderboard/.meteor/local/build'
at Object.Future.wait (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-  tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:398:15)
at Object.wrapper [as rename] (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/files.js:1350:24)
at Object.files.renameDirAlmostAtomically (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/files.js:810:11)
at [object Object]._.extend.complete (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/builder.js:482:11)
at /Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1933:13
at /Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2147:20
at /Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:264:13
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at /Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:257:29
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at /Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:255:18
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at /Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:246:23
at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:115:14)
at Object.capture (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:245:19)
at Object.exports.bundle (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:2040:31)
at /Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:554:24
at time (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/profile.js:231:28)
at Function.run (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/profile.js:377:12)
at bundleApp (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:544:34)
at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:591:35)
at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:821:28)
at /Users/kishanpatel/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.1.3.1wysac9++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:402:12
- - - - -
```

Any help regarding this problem of mine will be greatly appreciated!

Thanks!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It seems to be unhappy about your build folder.

I would stop your app, then just delete the build folder mentioned in the first line of the logged error

```
/Users/kishanpatel/Meteor/leaderboard/.meteor/local/build
```

and then restart meteor.

It will simply recreate the build folder, probably without the problem you have right now.

Comment: Thank you @mwarren. You've no idea how that little answer saved my day!