# Exited with code 8 @ node_modules/fibers/futures.js

Tags: meteor

```
Adams-MacBook-Pro:faze1app adamhanna$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/Desktop/apps/temp/faze1App ]]]]]      

=> Started proxy.                             
=> Started MongoDB.                           
=> Meteor 1.3.5.1 is available. Update this project with 'meteor update'.
W20160722-07:52:52.466(-7)? (STDERR)          
W20160722-07:52:52.468(-7)? (STDERR) /Users/adamhanna/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.3.2_4.1qxzz7q++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/mt-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/server-lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:300
W20160722-07:52:52.469(-7)? (STDERR)                        throw(ex);
W20160722-07:52:52.469(-7)? (STDERR)                              ^
W20160722-07:52:52.469(-7)? (STDERR) [object Object]
=> Exited with code: 8
```

The error doesn't tell me much, so it's hard to debug. It's only happening in this one project, so I'm sure it's project specific.

I've tried:

- Uninstalling / reinstalling meteor
- Updating meteor to the latest version
- Meteor reset
- [This solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31369872/meteor-wont-start-fibers-futures-js-throws-error-error-sqlite-corrupt-dat)
- [This other solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30383596/error-with-future-js-in-meteor-application)

Is there anyway to get more info out of the error rather than [object Object]?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SOLVED

Ok, so this is my fault, but it would be nice if the error was more descriptive.

Essentially, I need to connect my app to multiple mongoDB's, so I have the following in my server code:

```
var myOtherDatabase = new MongoInternals.RemoteCollectionDriver("mongodb://myOtherMongoURI");
myOtherCollection = new Mongo.Collection('stuff', { _driver: myOtherDatabase });
```

I have ufw set up on that other mongoDB and forgot to allow access from my new ip. My app wasn't able to connect and was throwing an err.